# How do I pass apikey as authorization in a POST/GET request in Karate Framework feature file

Tags: karate

This is the first time I am trying my hands at Karate for my work. I have a feature file that is a GET request and uses an authorization method as an apikey but when I am passing an authorization as a header its giving me an error

"required (...)+ loop did not match anything at input 'Scenario:'"

Below is my feature file for reference 
Feature: Get Profile

```
Background:
    * url 'https://csXXX-XXXX.XXXXXXXXX.net'
    * header Accept = 'application/json'
    * header Authorization = 'apikey XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX'
Scenario: Profile GET on an id
    Given path '/v1/Profile'
    And   param idProfile='XXXX'
    When  method get
    Then  status 200
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Feature: Get Profile

 Background:
     * url 'https://csXXX-XXXX.XXXXXXXXX.net'
     * header Accept = 'application/json'
     * header Authorization = 'apikey XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX'
 Scenario: Profile GET on an id
     Given path '/v1/Profile'
     And   param idProfile='XXXX'
     When  method get
     Then  status 200

Comment: yes that was a typo, above is the complete feature file, still getting error

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you missed the `Feature:` at the top of the file.

I suggest you use the quickstart or ZIP release, so you get a ready to use test to try: https://github.com/intuit/karate#getting-started

Comment: I have added the complete request above but still getting same error. I tried the example in the docs and it works fine but trying to use one where we can pass an APIKEY. can you please help?

Comment: @GAURAVDHINGRA time for me to ask you to follow this process, all the best: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue